# How do I merge multiple dataframes and add a column for dummies using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, merge, dummy-variable

I have a question about merging multiple dataframes and adding a column of dummies.

Now I have two original input dataframes. The first dataframe is answering the question "which color is your favorite?" The second dataframe is answering the question "On a scale from 1 to 7, to what extent do you dislike this color?"

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['01','02'],
                    'like_wave_1': ['red','red'],
                    'like_wave_2': ['red','yellow']})
print(df1)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['01','02'],
                    'dislike_wave1_yellow': ['7','2'],
                    'dislike_wave1_red':['1','1'],
                    'dislike_wave1_blue':['2','7'],
                    'dislike_wave2_yellow': ['7','1'],
                    'dislike_wave2_red':['1','2'],
                    'dislike_wave2_blue':['3','7']})
print(df2)
```

The following dataframe constructs the outline of my expected output dataframe.

```
list_id = ['01','02']
list_color = ['yellow','red','blue']
list_wave = ['1','2']
expand = list(product(list_id, list_color, list_wave))
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(expand, columns=['id', 'color', 'wave'])
print(df)
    id   color wave
0   01  yellow    1
1   01  yellow    2
2   01     red    1
3   01     red    2
4   01    blue    1
5   01    blue    2
6   02  yellow    1
7   02  yellow    2
8   02     red    1
9   02     red    2
10  02    blue    1
11  02    blue    2
```

I would like to add two columns to df:

(1) "like": a column to show the presence of whether a color has shown for a specific id in a specific wave (1 represents yes, and 0 represents no)

(2) "dislike".

Therefore my expected dataframe is:

```
    id   color wave  like  dislike
0   01  yellow    1     0        7
1   01  yellow    2     0        7
2   01     red    1     1        1
3   01     red    2     1        1
4   01    blue    1     0        2
5   01    blue    2     0        3
6   02  yellow    1     0        2
7   02  yellow    2     1        1
8   02     red    1     1        1
9   02     red    2     0        2
10  02    blue    1     0        7
11  02    blue    2     0        7
```

Could you please help me solve this problem? Thank you so much for answering!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to get both frames into a compatible format with the other:

DF1

```
# Get df1 into usable format
df1 = df1.set_index('id')
# Create Multi Index by splitting columns on '_'
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
# Stack to create long format frame
df1 = df1.stack().reset_index()
# Fix column names to match df2/output
df1.columns = ['id', 'wave', 'color']
# Set like to 1 for these since this table indicates likes
df1['like'] = 1
```

`df1`:

```
   id wave   color  like
0  01    1     red     1
1  01    2     red     1
2  02    1     red     1
3  02    2  yellow     1
```

---

DF2

```
# Get df2 into usable format
# Set index to ID
df2 = df2.set_index('id')
# Create Multi Index by splitting columns on '_'
df2.columns = df2.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
# Stack to create long format frame
df2 = df2.stack(level=[1, 2]).reset_index()
# Fix column names to match df1
df2.columns = ['id', 'wave', 'color', 'dislike']
# Turn "wave1" into 1, "wave2" into 2, ... etc.
df2['wave'] = df2['wave'].str.lstrip('wave')
```

`df2`:

```
    id wave   color dislike
0   01    1    blue       2
1   01    1     red       1
2   01    1  yellow       7
3   01    2    blue       3
4   01    2     red       1
5   01    2  yellow       7
6   02    1    blue       7
7   02    1     red       1
8   02    1  yellow       2
9   02    2    blue       7
10  02    2     red       2
11  02    2  yellow       1
```

---

Then `merge` the frames together:

```
# Merge On Common Columns
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on=['id', 'wave', 'color'], how='outer')

# Fill empty values in like and dislike with 0 (only 1s in source DF1)
# (Fill dislikes in case there are likes in df1 that are not dislikes in df2)
df3[['like', 'dislike']] = df3[['like', 'dislike']].fillna(0).astype(int)

# Sort Values and fix index (to match output in question)
df3 = df3.sort_values(
    ['id', 'color'], ascending=[True, False]
).reset_index(drop=True)
```

`df3`:

```
    id wave   color  like dislike
0   01    1  yellow     0       7
1   01    2  yellow     0       7
2   01    1     red     1       1
3   01    2     red     1       1
4   01    1    blue     0       2
5   01    2    blue     0       3
6   02    1  yellow     0       2
7   02    2  yellow     1       1
8   02    1     red     1       1
9   02    2     red     0       2
10  02    1    blue     0       7
11  02    2    blue     0       7
```

Comment: @HenryEcker you don't need to call the MultiIndex constructor; when you split columns and expand to True, they automatically become MultiIndex. It should simplify your code a bit.

Comment: @sammywemmy Thank you! This is one of my favourite parts of SO, always nice to learn something new.

Answer (score 1):

We can use [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/notebooks/Pivoting%20Data%20from%20Wide%20to%20Long.html) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/index.html) to reshape the individual dataframes before merging:

```
left = (df1.pivot_longer('id', 
                         names_to=('.value', 'num'), 
                         names_pattern=r".+_(.+)_(\d$)")
           .rename(columns={"wave":"color",
                            "num":"wave"})
           .assign(like = 1)
         )

left
 
   id wave   color  like
0  01    1     red     1
1  02    1     red     1
2  01    2     red     1
3  02    2  yellow     1


right = (df2.pivot_longer('id',
                          names_to=(".value", "dislike", "color"), 
                          names_pattern = r".+_(.+)(\d)_(.+)", 
                          sort_by_appearance=True)
           .rename(columns = {"dislike":"wave", "wave":"dislike"})
          )

right
 
    id wave   color dislike
0   01    1  yellow       7
1   01    1     red       1
2   01    1    blue       2
3   01    2  yellow       7
4   01    2     red       1
5   01    2    blue       3
6   02    1  yellow       2
7   02    1     red       1
8   02    1    blue       7
9   02    2  yellow       1
10  02    2     red       2
11  02    2    blue       7

right.merge(left, how = 'outer').fillna(0)

    id wave   color dislike  like
0   01    1  yellow       7   0.0
1   01    1     red       1   1.0
2   01    1    blue       2   0.0
3   01    2  yellow       7   0.0
4   01    2     red       1   1.0
5   01    2    blue       3   0.0
6   02    1  yellow       2   0.0
7   02    1     red       1   1.0
8   02    1    blue       7   0.0
9   02    2  yellow       1   1.0
10  02    2     red       2   0.0
11  02    2    blue       7   0.0
```

Comment: OMG this is so neat! Thank you so much!